# How to edit a text input from a list in react native?

Tags: react-native

How can you edit a text field from a list in React Native?

I think I should select the element with the id and then replace it with inputText, but I have no clue how to turn the text field into input.

Anyone got some advise or examples ?

Comment: Just use TextInput. Why do you want to use Text component if it has to be editable?

Comment: @jimmyweb What should I use ?

Comment: as I said before - TextInput ;)